# Confused about eliminating a strategy in calculation of mixed strategy nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

So I have a symmetric game with pay off matrice as

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    P1/P2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    0 & (0,0) & (0,1) & (0,2) & (0,3) & (0,4) & (0,5) \\
    1 & (1,0) & (1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) & (1,4) & (0,0) \\
    2 & (2,0) & (2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) & (0,0) & (0,0) \\
    3 & (3,0) & (3,1) & (3,2) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) \\
    4 & (4,0) & (4,1) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) \\
    5 & (5,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Now I have 3 options

1) Calculate the mixed strategy nash equilibrium of 6x6 game.

2) Eliminate 0 strategy for both players and end up with a 5x5 game and then calculate the mixed strategy nash equilibrium.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    P1/P2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    1 & (1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) & (1,4) & (0,5) \\
    2 & (2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) & (0,0) & (0,0) \\
    3 & (3,1) & (3,2) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) \\
    4 & (4,1) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) \\
    5 & (5,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

3)If the row player plays 0 then he has a pay off of 0. Likewise he knows that the column player also has a pay off of 0 if he plays 0 so can I eliminate strategies 0 and 5 for both players and make a 4x4 game and then calculate the mixed strategy nash equilibrium ?

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    P1/P2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & (1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) & (1,4)\\
    2 & (2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) & (0,0)\\
    3 & (3,1) & (3,2) & (0,0) & (0,0)\\
    4 & (4,1) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0)\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Whats the approach that I should take ?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math StackExchange! What I'm about to say often comes as a surprise to many people, but not everything in this world is code! Therefore, good practices for displaying things that are not code may not follow the same standards. You may be interested in checking MathJax notation (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting those matrices!

Comment: Thanks. Done !!